# Using different connection for Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using

```
Schema::connection('mysql_migrate')
```

so I can use a different connection for database migrations. But it returns

```
Access denied for user 'myMigrateUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

However, when I run it on the terminal using

```
php artisan migrate --database=mysql_migrate
```

It works. Am I missing out on something here?

Comment: It happened to me when it didn't recognized the environment, so it used the production one.

Comment: How are you using Schema::connection? Add some exmample code

Comment: `Schema::connection('mysql_migrate')->create('users', function($table) {
      $table->increments('id');
  });`